# How to get specific xpath in a node?

Tags: xpath

Any idea how to get /includes/images/large/BW93942/hermes-swift-retourne-kelly-32-indigo-1.jpg from here with it xpath?

```
/<img class="cloudzoom-gallery img-responsive cloudzoom-gallery-active" src="/includes/images/thumb/BW93942/xhermes-swift-retourne-kelly-32-indigo-1.jpg.pagespeed.ic.PQKVquZdzC.webp" data-cloudzoom="useZoom: '.cloudzoom', image: '/includes/images/BW93942/hermes-swift-retourne-kelly-32-indigo-1.jpg', zoomImage: '*/includes/images/large/BW93942/hermes-swift-retourne-kelly-32-indigo-1.jpg*' " pagespeed_url_hash="271624911" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

try Below

```
//img/@src
```

OR

```
//img[@class='cloudzoom-gallery img-responsive cloudzoom-gallery-active']/@src
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: it's not working this is what i want here is the link http://www.fashionphile.com/hermes-swift-retourne-kelly-32-indigo-93942 try to point on to the small product image below and inspect element that's the xpath i want but it's not working

Comment: there are so many small images present in that link.. which img src you want .. or you need all of them

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XPath string function [`substring-before`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before) to grab the part of the `@src` attribute which comes before `.pagespeed`. When applied the the HTML you posted, the XPath

```
substring-before(//img[@class="cloudzoom-gallery img-responsive cloudzoom-gallery-active"]/@src, ".pagespeed")
```

yields

```
/includes/images/thumb/BW93942/xhermes-swift-retourne-kelly-32-indigo-1.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks you really appriciate